# Digital Ocean Spaces Replication for Staging

Tags: amazon-s3, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

We're currently moving our setup from a few VPS to Digital Ocean. Our setup includes a staging site, which has a replica of our live db, however all E-Mails are caught using Mail Catcher and it has it's own storage location for assets, as we don't want to delete all production assets, when we delete a user on the staging system.

Therefore the question is: Is there a way to replicate all the assets from one DO space to another. Basically the idea is that if someone uploads an image on the prod site, it will be uploaded to the prod media bucket and should be replicated to the stage media bucket. Same when someone deletes a file in the prod media bucket (though I could live without this).

The only option to achieve my goals so far is to use [Rclone](https://rclone.org/) on a VPS using a cron job, as described by DO [here](https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/transfer-spaces-rclone/), however I hope there is a more "elegant" solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do it natively like S3 so rclone or something custom is your best bet - you can always OSS it to help the community